# Unable to install Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my entire 250GB HDD. No partions. Now when I try to install Windows 7, the installer says that

> No Drivers Found. Insert a CD/DVD or USB to complete the installation

I am guessing this is because of no partitions in my HDD. What to do? I cannot even unmount the volume or format it, because Ubuntu is already running in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must boot from windows7 cd. If still can't install windows you can format disk manaully with gparted live cd to empty space or ntfs partition.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I booted with gparted , deleted the entire volume and installed Win7 after it. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Was better if you first install Windows 7 and then Ubuntu and better than that define two separate partition For each of OS.
When you want to install Ubuntu, you should change hard drive partition format to Journal. This type of
partition format in Windows 7 not detected. To install Windows 7 you need a partition with NTFS or FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't even access the Ext drive format Ubuntu uses, you need to make a separate ntfs partition and install windows there

That's the best/easiest solution IMO